# 100 Reputation bonus upon joining new Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus

Why is a 100 reputation bonus awarded for logging in to a new Stack Exchange site?

This occurs if if you are an existing user of SE with some reputation on other sites.

> **+100**
> You've earned a bonus of 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites in the network

Comment: It's basically a shortcut for users who are already familiar with how [se] sites work.

Comment: 200 points to be able to comment is still in my opinion quite high for experienced users, as explained here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253824/is-it-a-good-way-for-stack-overflow-to-split-and-distribute-topics-over-differen/272396#272396

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Congratulations! One of your linked accounts has reached 200 reputation points, and as a result, all associated accounts are given a 100 point bonus.

The bonus is awarded because you have proven that you know your way around the basic features of any Stack Exchange website, and with those 100 extra points you can now comment, vote, flag and create bounties on all SE sites.

From here on out, on any *new* sites you join you'll also be given this bonus.

See [Award account association bonus automatically upon reaching 200 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep)

<sup><sub>Originally posted by yours truly on Meta.SE: [What is the association bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus/141649#141649)</sub></sup>

Comment: [There also this way of getting it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9iErT.png) (if you need an image).

Comment: Can I get this bonus multiple times?

Comment: You get it *once on each site*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what if i get 200 rep on other site? will i get ass. bonus again?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil: no, you don’t.