# How do I know a post is a community wiki post?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Is it only if it is tagged with "community-wiki" tag? Or are there some other indicators?

Comment: Sample CW post: [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251221); both question and answer are CW posts.

Comment: Compare that with a [regular question and answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254472/100-reps-are-provided-for-joining-new-se-sites), spot the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A post that doesn't have a specific user with avatar is a community wiki post. It will also say "community wiki" where the author usually is.

Tags have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

For example - this is a community wiki post.

See, no user avatar?