# How to get reputation as a newbie?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask how I could or should get reputation as a newbie. It's my first year in my education to an application developer, so I kinda don't have the "huge" knowledge or problems which I could post here. And if I'm asking newbie programming stuff it would be downvoted as hell I guess. I don't want to earn much reputation or stuff. Just enough to comment on Meta or upvote something.

So how could I earn some?

Comment: This is not the kind of questions that will get you reputation or upvotes either. Its not the question that matters but the way you describe your problem and how much info you give with the problem.

Comment: @Koen I didn't wanted to get points through this post, so it's just the way I describe it ? Even if my questions are newbie stuff?

Comment: first ask questions at the right place, second: you will not get downvoted for newbie questions - just for questions where you did not put any efford into

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's kinda funny but I would need 5 points to post there

Comment: @CarstenKönig Okay then. I saw some newbie questions before and it seemed that they were ignored and downvoted and stuff. So I wanted to be sure, but thanks

Comment: Build web site from scratch. First use ASP.NET forms after that mvc. I'm talking about .Net/C# because this was in stackoverflow before migration with this tags. After that you will have enough knowledge to answer questions.

Comment: @mybirthname ... please don't start with ASP.NET Webforms ... ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig probably it will be easy for him in the begging with webforms. But probably you are right, the mvc is the new technology.

Comment: @CarstenKönig I need to say that I'm not a completely newbie in programming. I'm pretty okay with C# and windows forms applications and get my own projects from my company to solve. But in comparison to your skills I'm like nothing

Comment: @Mauley Rep here **is not skill** so maybe you are a far better programmer that I will ever be - this site and the rep-system here is just a game for big (sometimes not so big) boys/girls - don't give to much to it (nor to some random downvotes - sadly those happens often in C#) - BTW: if you want to farm Rep just ask/answer LINQ Questions :P

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion No, I'm not. The post just got moved

Comment: @CarstenKönig It could be true tho, but it would be nice if I had enough points to upvote stuff and so on :P . But good to know, thanks :)

Comment: After migration, you are able to access meta, without 5 reputation. This is nice. Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow, [this is a site where we discuss about Stack Overflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: The simplest way is suggest an edit on some post. Once approved, it will give you 2 reputation points.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Well, I guess now I'm able to, thank you as well

Comment: Have patience, you will soon have get 15 rep if and then you can upvote posts. Also, once you get 200 rep on any site, [on all other SE sites, you get 100 rep as association bonus, so you never have to worry about being unable to vote again.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254472/100-reps-are-provided-for-joining-new-se-sites/254474#254474)

Comment: @nicael For example correct the topic name?

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I don't know exactly what you mean

Comment: Topic name, grammar, English, fix all the issues that you can see in the post, watch the [front page for a few minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest), and help clean up the posts by editing

Comment: Yes. Also correct grammar, improve formatting, etc...

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Okay , thanks you again. And thanks to the other as well! First I was kinda afraid that I get hated and downvoted for my post.

Comment: For starters, put your questions in the correct tags that may bring more views. You've got a C# question (one of the biggest tags) without C# as a tag. I looked at your profile, and noticed you had well worded questions with 0 upvotes or answers. That is odd. Then I noticed the tags.

Comment: FYI you now have reputation... your C# question on SO was worthy of an upvote. Due to the missing tag, it escaped attention. I added the C# tag just now, and +1'd the question as I do any well worded, worthy question.

Comment: Yes, it's a good question, and hopefully it will get more attention now because it has the proper tag, I upvoted it too. Always remember to add the language tag, else experts can't see the question.

Comment: @codenheim Wich kind of Tag's should I used in this post? I didn't know it, to be honest.

Comment: @Mauley C# if its a C# question in any way.

Comment: @codenheim Where did you add the C# tag?

Comment: In the tags bar. Maybe you didn't realize, but if you edit the question, you should see the tags. People use the tags to filter. C# experts potentially wont see  your question if you leave off C#, depending on the other tags. Not everyone look at the global question queue. They look at tag specific favorites filter .

Comment: @codenheim I thought I added it. I remember that I needed to edit my tag or title of post some days ago because I shouldn't use a tag in a title. But thanks for saying that

Comment: Maybe you are looking at the wrong question.

Comment: @codenheim Well , that makes sense.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Okay, should have used the tag. I guess I will be better with using the tags over the time. I don't know which tags are existing but I guess I will learn it.

Comment: Mauley, whether you like farming for reputation or not, you have to do it until you get the privileges that you desire for your level of participation. That means try to answer some questions.

Comment: Yes, with time you will learn, you can [look here to find a tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags), if you hover over any tag, you will see how many experts are following that tag, and also a lot of information about the tag, along with all the questions asked on that subject. Tags are very useful. Good luck.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Ahh, and now I recognized that the Tags are much more important than the title .. Well.. Now it makes sense. I'm pretty happy about it that you all helped me here. Thank you all :).

Comment: Just because you don't have that much experience doesn't mean you can't get reputation -- I had only 3 months of experience with JavaScript when I started out on Stack Overflow. Also, reputation doesn't really represent your skills as a programmer: posting many questions and/or answers even if they are bad will eventually get your reputation up to 20k (not that I recommend this sort of "rep-farming" activity).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy That's true. I just was a little bit afraid of asking stuff because some topics I found got hated and downvoted.

Comment: No one hates anyone here, as long as you are polite. There is a very good community around Stack Overflow.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I recognized here in that post. But now I should start to work.. at work.. :P. Have a nice morning,day or evening!

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I got one last question. The post got multiply marked as an duplicate. So what do I have to do?

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't effect you in any way. It is for future readers, all good answers on any topic are kept in a single post, and all copies are marked as duplicates of that canonical post. These are like sign posts pointing to the correct post. Users search using different keywords in Google, so if they search using the words you used, they will find this post and then will find the correct posts. Duplicates add value to the site because they make it easier for future users who are searching for the answer, and they don't impact you in any negative way.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Alright.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion what do you know about http://stackoverflow.com/users/2708705/no-one and http://stackoverflow.com/users/431925/anybody that I don't?  Why would Mauley being polite make them hate each other?

Comment: @Yakk: You did your research before posting :D