# Why can users below rep 5 participate in MSO?

Tags: support, meta, migration

That's the 2nd time today, I see a user with 1 rep appear on MSO via question migration

- [How to get reputation as a newbie?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275396/how-to-get-reputation-as-a-newbie)
- [How do i get a custom stack overflow url?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275444/how-do-i-get-a-custom-stack-overflow-url)

Is this intended behaviour (Did something change recently?), that the user can participate MSO, though rep would be too low when trying to ask the question directly on MSO?

Comment: [Apparently, at least one mod didn't know they could.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271202/whats-the-thought-behind-the-5-rep-limit-for-asking-questions-on-meta#comment93572_271202) I almost marked this a duplicate of that question, until I noticed this is a "why can they" not a "why can they not" question.

Comment: @bluefeet Well, good catch ;-). But you might get my intend.

Comment: What I can say for sure - nothing was changed recently regarding this behaviour :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, this is the intended behavior.

All sites behave this way: you have to earn at least 5 reputation on the main site to ask a question on the associated meta site, but a migration path from main->meta always exists to serve any *reasonable* meta questions that do get asked on main.

The 5-rep restriction exists primarily to thwart misuse: without it in place, new folks tend to get confused and ask main-site questions on meta, which is annoying for everyone involved. In addition, the tools for moderating spam and offensive content are slightly weaker on meta sites (there's no reputation penalty or quality-ban in place on meta). But if someone has a legitimate meta question and asks it on main, there's no reason not to move it to the proper location and answer it - indeed, before meta existed, it was reasonably common to ask such questions on the main site (although not particularly well-regarded).

Comment: Well, user 1 had to be convinced, though he vigorously defended biting and scratching, to accept that meta is needed. Sometime in the stone-age.

Comment: THX for the **clear** answer. As long there's no duplicate this should well serve any open questions.