# +100 trusted reputation on the site which reached the threshold

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, association-bonus

Today I asked a question and got 2 downvotes. However, I saw an increase of 596 total reputation in the upper bar. That is 6*100 points for "trusted on other sites" minus 4 for the downvotes. So far, so good.

However, I had 193 reputation on Stack Overflow before and there is no site where I actually reached the necessary 200 reputation which would give me the +100 trust bonus.

The only explanation to me is: someone accidentally upvoted, which gave +10, soo I reached 203 reputation, thus triggering the trust bonus update. Then, he removed that vote, so I went back to 193.

Then, the trust bonus calculator ran asynchronously and went through all accounts that have less than 200 reputation, which applies to all my accounts, including Stack Overflow.

IMHO, the account that triggers the trust bonus should be excluded from receiving the bonus, which is not the case for me:

[image: Accidental +96 reputation on Stack Overflow]

If someone could just upvote one of my questions again and then remove the upvote, maybe we'd see that same thing again.

And if a moderator would correct that undeserved reputation, please... (At the time of writing I have 289 points on Stack Overflow, which should be 189 instead)

My focus is on the word "other" in the description, because Stack Overflow is not an "other" site, but the site which triggered the bonus.

I read [100 Reps are provided for joining new Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254474/4136325) and the answer says "associated accounts", which IMHO also excludes the triggering account.

Also the question [Award account association bonus automatically upon reaching 200 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56506/273478) talks about "linked-to account", which I read as excluding.

Third, the accepted answer [why is my rep so low?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56478/273478) claims the same.

So, the common understanding seems to be that you get the bonus only on **other** sites.

Comment: Your honesty is commendable, but I'm pretty sure this is what's supposed to happen. I got 100 points on everything too.

Comment: @BiscuitBaker: it says "other" sites, so my impression was that SO should be excluded (which is "this" site, not "other" site).

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ what's your question as the question at the end doesn't really match your title.  Are you asking "why did I get the association bonus when I didn't hit 200 rep?  Or are you asking  "why did I get +100 on stack overflow when it triggered the association bonus?"

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ: nope, you get it for all sites including the site where you first reached the trigger level. You briefly reached 200+ so you earned it, however briefly.

Comment: @psubsee2003: the second. I know that I can cross limit and then fall back, still keeping badges etc. I've updated the title and added more info to the question. Initially I thought it was a coincidence of both occurences together and that all sites with more than 200 reputation are excluded from the bonus (which will actually be only one site).

Comment: The fact of you asking this question should be enough to give you that +100 rep because SO trusts you.

Comment: For what it's worth, you'll never receive the +100 rep again on that set of linked accounts, no matter what. Don't worry about that.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it.  The system here really works well... Even if this were a mis-application, there are plenty of other checks and balances that would prevent any abuses

Comment: I wish I could award a bounty for questions, too. Aside from that, in the grand scheme of things, +100 on an account is not a big deal, even though it may feel like that the first time it happens.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

There is nothing to correct here.

You reached the required trigger level, 200 points or more, fair and square. You may have reached it only briefly but you did so long enough for the system to determine that you were due the bonus.

The bonus applies to **all** your accounts, including the account that crossed the 200 point threshold. You've shown that you have enough experience with Stack Exchange sites that you deserved to have access to a basic set of functionality across all sites, plus a little 'thank you' for using more than one site in the network.

Besides, why would other accounts suddenly have more reputation than the one that earned you the bonus?

Also see [Should the Association Bonus be given to the account crossing 200 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190506/should-the-association-bonus-be-given-to-the-account-crossing-200-rep)

The only confusion here is the word *other*; the message is re-used for all accounts, including the original one. I'd not worry about it, that's just the developers being lazy and keeping things simple. Would a different message have made much of a difference here?

Comment: Ok, should we change the wording from "other" to "this" for the site which reached the threshold?

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ: It would also be wrong to just change the word "other" to "this", because the reason behind the award is not only that you are trusted on "this" but that you also are active on other sites in the SE network. If anything should change, it would have to be a detailed explanation of why you got the reputation on that site (something like this entire answer from Matijn), and frankly I think that is a bit of an overkill to have in a reputation change notice...

Comment: @awe: I didn't want to change all of the notifications from "other" to "this", just the one which reached the threshold. Another option would be "You have earned ... because we trust you on StackOverflow" (naming the site specifically), which would be the same text for all notifications again.

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ Instead of "trusted on other sites" how about just - you have [reached 100 reputation/become trusted user] on (at least) one network site.

Comment: @user568109: take into account that any future SE sites joined also receive the bonus, the message has to continue to make sense then.

Comment: Suppose I already have 200+ rep in one account and have received +100 in all accounts and if my another account reaches 200, will I again get +100 rep in all accounts?

Comment: @Apurva: the moment that one account reached 200+, you get the bonus on top of that account and all others. You get the bonus *just once* per account; the switch is network wide. You cannot set the switch again on another account, because it is already enabled.