# What is the median reputation level on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, data-explorer

A silly question occurred to me. I was wondering if there were any way to know what number is the median reputation level here on Stack Overflow.

Just to clarify, I'm not looking for the *mean* reputation but for the *median* reputation. That is to say the threshold where there are as many users below as users who are above.

I thought of giving [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) a try but I'm totally unfamiliar with it. Therefore, besides the actual number, I'm also interested in *how* it can be retrieved so I can make my future own queries.

Comment: I'd be pretty shocked if it was anything other than 1.

Comment: You should also consider if users are active or not in the question as I would wager there are a lot of low rep users who are not active and where never very active at all.

Comment: Maybe it would be relevant not to include 1-rep users in the query then.

Comment: Why would it be more relevant to include 2-rep users?

Comment: I guess 2-rep users have been participating at least once in SO where 1-rep users have just subscribed.

Comment: 1-rep users also includes people who have lost more rep then gained.

Comment: The 1 rep users start listing at page ~42000.  Page 21000 lists the median, it is 21.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(Reputation)  FROM (SELECT TOP 50 percent Reputation FROM Users ORDER BY Reputation) as halfbyrep` says it is 1. Add a `WHERE` clause to narrow down the selection of what users 'count'.

Comment: Interesting question! I don't think that the median will tell you much, but I'd be interested to see if a frequency distribution chart (or even a histogram)  showed distinct 'peaks' or a 'mode' other than 1. Most social sites will show a peak of  '1's (people who wandered in once and found nothing to draw them back), a broad population of users with a Gaussian (or a Poisson)  profile, and a far-out peak  of obsessive geeks with an upper bound constrained by the number of minutes in the day and a disturbing willingness to push the known human limitations of eating sleeping and personal hygiene.

Comment: @Nile I'd like to see that histogram

Comment: @Nile, I very much doubt that the 'obsessive geeks' form a peak. Obsessive geekiness is a spectrum and there should be plenty of intermediate geeks to smooth out the distribution.

Comment: Is it possible to `GROUP BY year(user.CreationDate)` or by `user.LastAccessDate` to see if any intrayear trends pop up?

Comment: Given that users are signing up all the time, and many are not active, it's very likely that the median is and will always be one.

Comment: loosely related: [Distribution of Reputation on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272749/distribution-of-reputation-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

1. Go to the [users > reputation > all](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) page
2. Look at the last page in the list of pages.  Divide that value by two
3. Go to that page by editing the query string parameter for the page number.  (At the time of this posting, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=56205&tab=reputation&filter=all) is the appropriate page.)
4. If the users on that page don't all have the same reputation (at the time of this post, they do all have the same reputation) compute the median rep of the users on that page.

At the time of this post, the median rep is 1.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for answering. Wouldn't it be any way to prevent the inactive users from being added in the calculation of the median rep?

Comment: @D4V1D How do you define "active"?

Comment: I'd give a try in guessing that we are talking about users who have *at least* asked *one* question or *one* answer. Just a thought.

Comment: @D4V1D There are people with hundreds of thousands of rep that have never asked a single question.

Comment: Users who have interacted with the site somehow? (*edited my comment above*).

Comment: @D4V1D At one point one of the 300K+ rep users had not been seen here for over 4 years. Is that active? Should that user be counted (IIRC he visited after that, but there will be others).

Comment: @D4V1D Does registering an account count as interaction, if so, that won't filter out anyone.  Also keep in mind none of the extracts will include deleted posts, so you won't see any actions for a user that asked one question and had it deleted.

Comment: Might be interesting to see for users with at least 10 non deleted questions + answers.

Comment: @Servy I would have to say that registration doesn't count as interaction. I get that deleted posts won't be included. So, we can miss a certain number of accounts but we thusly could get a more accurate number that if all accounts were included. This would not be related to the last connection date though.

Comment: I would just exclude users with a message containing "please kindly".

Comment: Why not just exclude everyone with a rep of exactly 1?  We already know there are a lot of them.

Comment: @Kevin See [Hans Passant's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296967/what-is-the-median-reputation-level-on-so#comment207097_296967) and [Becuzz](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296967/what-is-the-median-reputation-level-on-so#comment207229_296970) comments.

Comment: is it possible to only include those who had a reputation change within the last 3 months?

Comment: RE: Users with interactions. Basically any user interaction for a new user is going to cause a bronze badge. Just look for users with at least one badge. Even with 1 reputation, if they have a badge, they have interacted somewhere.

Comment: I did not know 1-rep users was so common. Does the query count users that were deleted, and moved to community accounts (or whatever the correct terms are)? I always see rep over 1000 on SO, and rarely see rep of just 1, unless the user is new as of that week.

Comment: @onebree That's because, by definition, you only see the users who are interacting with the site (unless you go searching through random user profiles.)

Answer (score 61):

After looking at [rene's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296970/4320665), I ran my own query filtering out anyone with 1 rep and got an answer of 21.  For anyone interested the query is thus:

```
select avg(reputation) median from
(select reputation, 
rnasc = row_number() over(order by reputation),
rndesc = row_number() over(order by reputation desc)
 from [users]
 where reputation > 1
) b
where rnasc between rndesc - 1 and rndesc + 1
```

Comment: It's still 21, if you exclude users with 101 reputation (site association bonus only).

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll leave the check mark on Servy's [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296969/2788131) though as it's this very one that made me find `21` (1-rep excluded) median reputation :) @ChristianStrempfer Interesting, although I'm quite sure there are other ways to reach 101 rep rather than subscribe + site association bonus only so you it's not 100% accurate.

Comment: @D4V1D aren't the chances of the latter (bonuses) leading to that reputation high enough compared to the former, that it would be less erroneous overall to exclude 101?

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Sorry, as English is not my primary language, I didn't get all of your comment. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: @D4V1D I was wondering that isn't the number of people with 101 reputation primarily those that get bonuses? You mention *although I'm quite sure there are other ways to reach 101 rep* but other than bonuses, it seems unlikely people get exactly 101 rep.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 I totally agree with you. 101-rep users are **primarily** those that get bonuses but it's not 100% accurate as, even though it seems unlikely people get exactly 101 rep, it's still possible to reach that threshold *without* having gotten the bonuses, just by upvotes / accepted answers / etc.

Comment: @D4V1D Exactly! Consider **10000** users with 101rep who got there by bonuese, and say **100** got there by upvotes (1%). So if you **include all 101 rep users you include 10k erroneous entries**, but if you **exclude all 101 rep users you only discard 100 erroneous entries**. I feel that the latter leads to lesser error.

Comment: @D4V1D: such a user should have 201 reputation: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285130/100-trusted-reputation-on-the-site-which-reached-the-threshold

Comment: @prakharsingh95 I ran Becuzz's [query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297074/2788131) after having added `and reputation != 101` and the result is still **21**.

Comment: Instead of filtering out reps of 1 and 101 which could include users with some activity, just **filter out user who have never asked a question or answered one**. I wouldn't care if a user left 1000 comments but never posted answer or question.

Answer (score 44):

The existing posts answer your question perfectly, but for information, here is what the reputation distribution looks like. You can obtain the data with [the following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/326915/reputation-distribution):

```sql
SELECT Reputation AS reputation, COUNT(Reputation) AS distribution
FROM Users
GROUP BY Reputation
ORDER BY Reputation
```

But because Jon Skeet, logarithmic scales are mandatory in order to obtain a readable graphic. It's fairly easy with Matlab, for instance:

```matlab
data = readtable('QueryResults.csv');
data.reputation = str2double(data.reputation);
data.distribution = str2double(data.distribution);

loglog(data.reputation, cumsum(data.distribution) / sum(data.distribution));
title('Cumulative reputation distribution');
xlabel('Reputation');
ylabel('Normalized cumulative distribution');
```

[image: Cumulative reputation distribution]

Notice that people with 1 rep represent almost 61% of the Stack Overflow members, hence your answer: **the median rep is 1**.

Comment: great answer, it helped

Comment: I love how Jon Skeet makes the whole distribution skewed and you had to apply a logarithmic scale lol. +1.

Comment: A very trivial note: The "X: 1" tooltip blocks the "1" in 10^0. I was confused why there is 0^0 on the graph.

Comment: It's interesting that there's a slight hiccup in the curve after a rep of around 100. Perhaps that's due to people gaining the 100 rep cross-site bonus when making their first SO post after posting on other SE sites but then not making many more after that. It might also be related to something that happens after making 200 rep, when members start to get ranked. I can't think what though.

Comment: @samgak I think it's between 200 and 300, which is because of people earning the association bonus after having gained 200 rep on SO, so jumping from 200 to 300.

Comment: @samgak You can actually also see a little jump from 100 to 101, which is due to the 12k users with 101 rep, of which most probably got to 200 rep on another site and got the association bonus on SO.

Answer (score 42):

It is 1 based on [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/326338/what-is-the-median-reputation-level-on-so)

```
-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/7227860/578411
select avg(reputation) median from
(select reputation, 
rnasc = row_number() over(order by reputation),
rndesc = row_number() over(order by reputation desc)
 from [users] 
) b
where rnasc between rndesc - 1 and rndesc + 1
```

... which is a big lie. The actual median is...

#### 92

As indicated by [@Dronehinge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3041194/dronehinge) the users that really should have been deleted shouldn't be part of the population.

Those [registered user deletion rules are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146450/delete-old-unloved-users/146452#146452):

1. The user has not visited Stack Overflow in six months
2. The user has only 1 reputation,
3. no visible posts,
4. and no other accounts on the network

The last requirement turns the new version of the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/327337/better-median) into a multi-database beast, with temp tables and database cursors:

```sql
-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE
                         and database_id <> db_id() -- skip current db as well
                     
declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_accounts ( accountid int)

-- create a union of all accountid's across
-- all databases
set @sql = N'insert into #all_accounts '                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = @sql + N'select accountid from ' + QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) + N'.dbo.users'
              
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
   IF (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) 
   BEGIN   
     set @sql = @sql + N' 
     union 
     '
   END
end
close db_c
deallocate db_c

print @sql
exec(@sql) -- execute the insert with the unions

-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/7227860/578411
select avg(reputation) median from
(select u.reputation, 
rnasc = row_number() over(order by u.reputation),
rndesc = row_number() over(order by u.reputation desc)
 from [users] u
 -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146450/delete-old-unloved-users/146452#146452
 where u.lastaccessdate > dateadd(m, -6, getdate()) -- active in last 6 months ago
 and u.reputation > 1 -- more then 1 rep 
 and exists (select 1 from posts where owneruserid = u.id) -- visible post
 and exists (select 1 from #all_accounts where accountid = u.accountid)  --other accounts in the network
) b
where rnasc between rndesc - 1 and rndesc + 1

select count(*)
from #all_accounts

select count(*)
from users

select count(*)
from users u
left outer join #all_accounts acc on acc.accountid = u.accountid
 where acc.accountid is null

drop table #all_accounts
```

Comment: I wonder what it is if you remove all the like One Million users that should have been auto-deleted by the system but have not b.c of the ridiculous throttle.

Comment: Interestingly, I ran it and filtered out all the 1 rep users and the answer it gave me was 21.  Still not very high.

Comment: @Becuzz If I were you, I'd post that query. It's more useful in my opinion.

Comment: @mason I posted it if you are interested.

Comment: Instead of filtering out reps of 1 and 101 which could include users with some activity, just **filter out user who have never asked a question or answered one**. I wouldn't care if a user left 1000 comments but never posted answer or question.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich What about users who haven't asked or answered questions but have made edits?

Comment: You all don't realize how much I hate the practice from statisticians to change the rules if they don't like the outcome...

Comment: If we change that to only one month, so we only have 'active' users, we get 121: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/327445/the-real-median-on-so

Comment: Well done, rene. Though now it looks sorta painful...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: 1 year ½ after, this number has decreased and is now at 91.

Comment: Thank you. Idk how anyone could comment 1 with a straight face