# Etiquette for editing a high-rep user's question tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, reputation

Is there any etiquette for editing a high-rep user's question tags? I'd ask the user directly in a comment, but he's been offline for a few days. I went ahead and [edited his tags](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30592022/revisions), but I'm turning to MSO for future advice.

Comment: As long as the change in tag doesn't conflict with the intent and better categorize the question, reputation doesn't matter.

Comment: I want to say that reputation doesn't matter in any case. You shouldn't take into consideration the reputation level when taking actions. If a post needs to be amended, do it. If you must downvote a 300k-rep user because you don't agree (MSO) or because the post is poorly written (SO), do it. Reputation level is a biais that I tended to have when interacting on the site. I don't do anymore (in fact, I just edited a 13k-rep user's answer and [I have been thanked for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908091/simplifying-some-jquery-code-of-keyup-inputs/30908210#comment49854443_30908210))

Comment: Also note that even high rep users were once low rep users. An old post from a high rep user may still be low quality/off topic or bad in other ways due to inexperience (at the time, hopefully...)

Comment: BTW, almost 10k rep - is pretty high yourself.

Comment: @JohnSaunders ecspecially [since the median is 1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296967/what-is-the-median-reputation-level-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Just because a user has high rep doesn't mean they have high rep in the area that they asking the question in. Almost all of my rep is from the [tag:python] tag. It's certainly possible while posting a question dealing with JS I might confuse some terms or not be as clear as I could in my main area of expertise.

Comment: If you make my question or answer better, then I benefit as it's more likely to attract votes. Everyone else benefits because there's more knowledge available. Win win FTW.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

When improving a post, the reputation of its author has no significance.

We don't have an upper class that is immune to the regular quality control mechanisms on the site. When there occasionally happens to be a high rep user that thinks so, they will be gently corrected by the community.

Comment: Coming from a user with 269k rep, that's good advice. I just didn't want to step on any toes. Thanks all.

Comment: You completely miss the point; the relevance of an opinion is **not** predicated on the persons reputation *score* or lack there of.

Comment: I think lower-rep users are concerned with hostile down-voting from high-rep users which leads to these kind of questions popping up every once in a while.

Comment: @xxbbcc that seems like a rather misguided worry, given that any user above 150 points can engage in hostile down-voting and it's likely not to be the most invested users (who know that there's very active moderation) who do it. Apart from closevoting, there's actually very little that higher-rep users can do to bully newer users.

Comment: @Pekka웃 but that downvote means I'm one step further form shiny badge or privilege....high rep users (30k+) are 'immune' to that worry.

Comment: @Pureferret I don't really follow - a downvote is two points; one upvote gets you ten. If you're *any* good, you can offset five hostile downvotes with a simple contribution.

Comment: @Pureferret, while that happens from time to time, I don't think it is frequent enough to make it a factor in deciding when to correct a post.

Comment: @RSahu I completely agree, just playing devil's advocate.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree with that. But upvotes are scarce on SO at times, and newbies can be easily spooked.

Comment: "We don't have an upper class" - You can summon SO's upper class by using the magic word 'forum' and watching them come out of the woodwork.

Comment: @corsiKa for a stronger effect, use "I am new to this forum"

Comment: @Pureferret maybe, but there is little we can do about that except assure folks that it's unlikely to happen. The world is not perfect

Comment: @Pekka웃 You're right in your reasoning about the value of downvote vs upvote - the problem is that nowadays it's much harder to get upvoted than historically. It's also my observation that if a lower-rep user (correctly) answers a question at the same time when a high-rep user does (correctly _or_ incorrectly), the high-rep user is more likely to get upvoted. (When I say "incorrectly", I don't mean a glaringly bad answer, just something that seems good enough but misleading.)

Comment: I get the feeling higher rep users have a higher propensity to downvote, based on their policing and more detailed knowledge of what is good and bad.  Whereas low rep either dont know or dont care as much.  I dont know if there are imperics on this.

Comment: @Jon that's very likely true!

Comment: @xxbbcc I agree with what you say, but it still doesn't seem very convincing evidence that there is a massive systemic problem causing newbies to be afraid of more experienced users to the point that they don't call them out when they're wrong.

Comment: Personally, I tend to equate rep with experience on the site (more or less equivalent to number of posts that some forums display), and worry that they have more experience on the website than I do, and therefore know more about how to ask the question correctly.

Answer (score 6):

The reputation of a user is **not irrelevant**. It carries valuable information. All SE sites take reputation seriously. Most user privileges are derived from it. It sounds heart-warming to say "reputation of the author has no significance", but that would be an incorrect over-simplification.

Ultimately, the reputation of the author should not influence the worth of a posting. However, there is always a possibility that **I might be mistaken** in my judgement myself. If I see the author of a post has high reputation, I'll check to the main fields of his/her expertise (unless I know already). If he/she is an expert in the field, chances I might be missing something are *much* higher. I'll check twice whether I might be wrong after all.

In a world without perfect information (and that's the only world where SE sites in their current form make sense), we have to take such hints into consideration to manage our time and energy as best as we can.

But that's also the extent of it. High reputation can be the result of excessive time spent on the site, or it can come from other fields irrelevant to the post at hand. And even experts can be wrong or miss a spot ...

Comment: The danger is that looking at a poster's reputation can influence your voting behavior. When faced with an unclear question from a high-rep user, you might think "I don't understand it so it must be *good*: +1!", and from a low-rep user "I don't understand it so it must be *bad*: -1!"

Comment: @Jongware: Among all uncertainty, one thing is certain: nobody should be voting for posts he/she does not understand.