# Yin and Yang for voting

Tags: discussion

Should we make sure that the voting tends towards positive messages?

Sometimes with posts on Stack olOverflow, I feel that the negative response seems incorrect.

With this question of mine [SO : copy data from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123872/how-to-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another),  I couldn't understand the down vote. Likewise this question here [SO : 64 bit version of CharLowerBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093908/is-there-a-64-bit-version-of-charlowerbuff).

Whilst I accept that these are all opinion based, I feel that perhaps we should encourage a positive average vote, and if the number of negative votes cast is too high, start requesting that the user finds more positive things to say, before being allowed to down vote.

Comment: i mean... voting on SO is already overwhelmingly positive.

Comment: Isn't it '*Yin and yang*'?

Comment: There's actual numbers backing up what Kevin B says. On average users vote up more often than they vote down.

Comment: I wonder though... Does that only count votes on posts that haven't been deleted? I don't recall.

Comment: @KevinB I can't remember either. I think it was Shog9 that posted the chart and I'm sure he said whether it did or not but I can't remember what the answer was. Sometimes I wish there was a tag just for posts containing useful statistics but really I wish I'd just remember to favorite them.

Comment: There's a bunch of data here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299930/voting-history-statistics-request/300520#300520

Comment: Wait as in you wouldn't be allowed to downvote until you've upvoted 'enough'?  A)How can we expect voting to be truly a representation of intent if we police it this way?   B) are you open to the opposite? Someone who NEVER downvotes to be forced to do so before he can upvote some more?

Comment: I've made 11 times more downvotes than upvotes.  I would be cut off for ever:(

Comment: You also would be pretty badly off.  If you were obliged to stop upvoting until your downvotes caught up, and assuming you emit downvotes at the same average rate as you have on your account so far, you will be eligible to upvote again in 118 years.

Comment: Odd that you claim that  users should have a balance of yin and yang in their voting, rather than predominately using one form of vote, and  yet you've cast **45 times** more upvotes than downvotes.  Clearly your voting patterns are completely out of balance, and you're not doing your job of properly indicating that the low quality content that you see is marked as such.  If you honestly think that this proposal is a good idea, you should fix your own voting patterns first to be a good example of balanced voting patterns before suggesting that it be enforced by the system.

Comment: @Servy Whenever votes are supposed to be, "balanced", users invariably mean people should be downvoting less, it seems.  Now, if only we could get people to upvote less...

Comment: @Servy 45 is nothing.  The last meta poster to suggest more effort from curators had a ratio of 160.  It's always someone else's fault when there is a perceived problem, and it's always someone else's effort required to try and fix it:(

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that most of the content on SO is of positive quality. Maybe review and see the front page a bit more? And that's only what we see, after the hard working folks that monitor tags close and remove abysmally bad posts before you can even see them. It should be the contrary, prevent people from asking questions until there are globally more opened questions than closed. (or something that doesn't deadlock, rather...)

Comment: My ratio of 45 is a positive effort.  I see questions which are "unclear what your are asking" where I understand their problem and have a solution, which are deleted before I can help the poster.  My question heading describes yin-and-yang - balance, but really I feel for the people who are bemused by negative response, with no explanation given to them on how to "improve" their questions.  For that reason the body of my question describes a positive trend to voting.  For this question (and at least the one of mine, I pointed out), I have gained extra negative marks.

Comment: I would really appreciate why the scores are negative - as the community seems to think positively about the answer to this question, and I fail to understand why my question (and its comments and answers) about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123872/how-to-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another are worth deleting for my on-going attempt to be a good SO citizen

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Whilst I accept that these are all opinion based, I feel that perhaps
>   we should encourage a positive average vote, and if the number of
>   negative votes cast is too high, start requesting that the user finds
>   more positive things to say, before being allowed to downvote.

This would be pointless on Stack Overflow. It's a big site. Some users spend nearly all of their network time curating posts in various review queues or chat rooms. The sample of the thousands of daily posts they see is decidedly those who are already known to have quality issues.

Of course, they're going to vote more down then up. And then there might be users who browse highly voted questions to dig in and write great answers to. Of course, they're going to have more upvotes then downvotes.

With a site as massive as this one, and with a userbase as diverse as this one, enforcing a certain ratio of up to downvotes would be pointless and damaging and would solve absolutely no issues.

Just one example of how your system can easily be circumvented:

- Suppose I'm a user who curates content that is overwhelmingly downvote worthy.
- Suppose the system enforced a 25% minimum upvote rate

I could just go through the most upvoted posts of all time and add one every time I run close to the limit. Now what? You only managed to inflate some scores

Answer (score 15):

There are a lot of issues surrounding how the site's system would provide such functionality as we currently have nothing to do this.

> Should we make sure that the voting tends towards positive messages?

What or who defines what "positive" is? Are you saying positive is only upvotes? Because in a very real way, downvotes are positive as they move the bad content down away from the good. This is one of the site's intentions.

> Sometimes with posts on stackoverflow, I feel that the negative
>   response seems incorrect.

I'm sure there will be times when arguably the vote was probably not the best thing to do, but it being wrong is just someone's opinion. Who is right and who is wrong? Why is that other person wrong and you right? What when someone calls your vote is wrong, up or down, would you.. just accept their opinion is right? I don't think anyone would really be happy with this, anyone who feels they might I am sure would not once it was in play.

You also have to consider that the downvote you don't think is "right" may well be justified and was just for something A) you never thought of, and B) you actually agree with once you hear the explanation.

Such things are entirely subjective, and so it's impossible to *dictate* what is right and wrong. It's just not practical.

Per person opinion driven voting and flagging is the only real way to let community moderate the sites, maybe some tweaks could be possible but the basis has to be without any dictating of how and when to vote. Also, it isn't a bad thing to have varied opinions.

> Whilst I accept that these are all opinion based I feel that perhaps
>   we should encourage a positive average vote and if the number of
>   negative votes cast is too high

Suggesting there should be any kind of average at all means we're enforcing an opinion on that person, then the voting is dictated, and is still someone's opinion. You state "too negative" so someone (even a group) would need to determine a threshold of some kind as to what is too negative, but then it's just their opinion instead of the first person who's average they deem is too high.