# What does IsHighRepEarner field in Personalized Prediction Data feature stand for?

Tags: support, reputation, personal-data

I noticed that there is a `IsHighRepEarner` boolean field, in the SO [Personalized Prediction Data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) JSON file that can be downloaded by each user. Just out of a curiosity, what exactly this field stands for? Do SO have some fancy algorithm to detect users that are exploiting the reputation system and trying to earn reputation as fast as possible without bringing much value to the community? Or is it just some measure of `reputation per week` for example?

Comment: It is actually much more difficult to earn rep while not contributing to the community than people seem to think. Rep _usually_ comes from other people finding your contributions useful, so it doesn't really follow that you would be able to gain a large amount of rep without contributing useful content, and even if you were to do so, what nefarious deeds would you _really_ be able to accomplish?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's nothing fancy. It's just an indicator of whether you've passed an arbitrary reputation threshold on the site, telling the system whether you are a "high-rep user" or not. I don't know the exact number for this particular system as we use different values to define "high rep" in a lot of different places. Most commonly it just means you've earned at least 1,000 reputation.

Comment: If this seems low to anyone, just remember that the vast majority of registered users on Stack Overflow have 1 reputation. (1-rep users start on page 69,516 of the Users page currently... out of 219,253 total pages, which means roughly 5.4million of SO's 7.9million users have 1 reputation only.

Comment: @TylerH In that case, maybe there should be a `IsVeryHighRepEarner` field too for anyone with 10k+. And a `IsVeryVeryHighRepEarner` for 20k. And `IsVeryVeryVeryHighRepEarner` for 50k. etc....

Comment: and also `IsJonSkeet` for all of the 1M rep users.

Comment: @DavidG Those fields would be almost useless. And instead, a `Reputation` field should be enough.

Comment: @Cœur You realise it was a joke right?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296967/what-is-the-median-reputation-level-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I got the `IsHighRepEarner` to with my 600 rep, so i think the system is counting you as a **high rep** at 500.

Comment: @Turnip but Jon only has 997,576 right now!

Comment: 500 rep for "high rep user" sounds right. That's when you get the cross site +100 bonus isn't it?

Comment: @Draco you get that at 200.

Comment: @animuson Shucks, there goes my memory. I must be getting old.

Comment: I’m not a high rep earner on my main site, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

(Maybe some sites don’t have this field active or it’s just a bug)

Comment: @bmike Personalized prediction data only exists for Stack Overflow, and always loads the data for Stack Overflow regardless of what site you are on.

Comment: That makes sense - I do diddly on this site so you’re right I haven’t cleared 1k here. Thanks for clarifying it’s a SO_HighRepUser flag in code. The URL to generate the data does resolve against other sites and the tag prediction values look spot on for all the sites I just checked (none of which was SO)