# Will the reputation in SO teams be merged to main profile?

Tags: support, reputation, stack-overflow-for-teams

Can we earn (or lose) reputation in Stack Overflow teams and will that reputation be added to the main profile?

Is the reputation seperate per team?

Will our main profile's reputation and privileges be shifted to teams upon joining?

Comment: No, the reputation in teams is separate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is it seperate per team?

Comment: Yes, it is separate per team. See [Coming Soon: Stack Overflow For Teams!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/562675)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reputation earned per team is *separate*, and counted *per team*.  Reputation earned in teams is not going to affect your main site reputation (with one exception, see below). You should see team accounts as if they were accounts on separate Stack Exchange sites.

From a [comment by Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364145/coming-soon-stack-overflow-for-teams#comment562675_364171):

> Rep is separate from main (and even from other teams where you might participate). There's no 'bleed over' of privileges (or a revocation of them, such as what happens if you're suspended).

*Teams for Stack Overflow* was originally called *channels*, and [this post from Tim Post (the same)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams) announcing channels states:

> When you operate within a channel, all of the privileges you earn (including reputation, etc.) remain specific to *that* channel, where your ability to contribute will grow over time, depending on how the channel is configured.

---

The one exception was the [association bonus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254472/100-reps-are-provided-for-joining-new-se-sites), the 100 points you earn on every site once *one* of your accounts has reached 200 points. When Teams initially launched, users could earn the association bonus by earning 200 reputation on a Team. This unintended feature was patched on 4 February 2020, so Teams participation no longer awards the bonus.

This wasn't a retroactive change, though, so any user who had earned it prior to the fix kept the bonus.

Comment: Now that's interesting... about the association bonus. I guess if that's actually true that's another thing to remember for questions asking how person X can have the association bonus when they don't have an account with 200 rep... and maybe something I should add to the association bonus FAQ.

Comment: @Catija yep! that one is true. and probably good for the FAQ :)

Comment: Thanks, @ChanceHeath Tim had also thought it would also go the other way but it *doesn't*... I'm guessing that's by design or will that be changed at some point?

Comment: to Tim's point, I think it was originally more like "unintentionally by design". We sort of forgot to prevent it in the Alpha, but ended up finding it to be a feature rather than bug. (As you know) the purpose of the association bonus is to gives users who have shown some basic understanding of how the Stack Exchange system works a boost past the initial site restrictions. Since Teams is based on the same set of mechanics, we believe that showing prowess in Teams is applicable elsewhere on the site.

Comment: @ChanceHeath Oh, sure! Absolutely. I was more curious whether showing prowess on the *network* is applicable to Teams. :) It's somewhat odd to see a bunch of Mods on the Mod team with only 1 rep.

Comment: ha! good point. that’s an odd sight to see. fortunately, most actions on Teams require no rep.

Comment: What's the point in being able to earn the assoc bonus in a team without being able to be granted there?

Comment: @iBug: what makes you think the assoc bonus is not granted in teams?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm in Charcoal Teams and I've never got any "+100 assoc bonus".

Comment: @iBug: ah, indeed, I don't have it either in my teams. The whole thing is 'unintentionally by design' as Chance stated, and since you don't need rep on teams to do most things anyway, it doesn't really matter.