# Display a summary of SO Teams in the main profile page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, stack-overflow-for-teams

According to my previous question,

> [Will the reputation in SO teams be merged to main profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369596/2408342)

it is clear that **SO Teams reputation is completely invisible to the public**.

---

I think that reputation will be much worth if a summary of Stack Overflow teams reputation be displayed on the main profile page and in the Flair. The users who are concerned about their privacy should be able to hide it from the settings page.

Just a simple line may be,

> **2.6K reputation on 4 teams.**

Comment: Strongly disagree. Both team membership and team reputation should be private everywhere (besides on the actual site of that team).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Why? Team names doesn't have to be published...

Comment: Then User can choose to display or hide it from the settings page may be

Comment: Can you explain what value having reputation on a Team adds to your SO profile?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Numbers for the sake of numbers don't really achieve anything. Simply saying "this user has some arbitrary amount of reputation on a private Team that you can't view" does absolutely nothing to enhance their public profile. Nobody knows what kinds of questions are actually being asked on that Team, nobody knows the voting culture of that Team, and thus nobody can know if that number actually correlates to any kind of relevant skill on the site outside of "is helpful to their Team."

This information simply doesn't belong in a public profile. It's separated for a reason.