# Are users with 200 reputation points on a team getting association bonuses again?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, association-bonus

I know [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369598/6380541) says that was patched, but I also have [this user](https://stackexchange.com/users/20318541/techbot?tab=accounts) that proudly proclaimed in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8845454#8845454) that they got the association bonus through Teams, and I can see they got one on both SO and MSE 12 hours ago. I'm aware there could technically be a deleted 200+ reputation account somewhere, but given that this is an account used for a bot, it would be a pretty effort-intensive troll if it is.

If that is true, then can this please be patched again, as it opens up all sorts of possibilities for voting/bounty fraud, and massive sock rings now that Teams is free for up to 50 users?

Comment: I still haven't joined the team, so I could test it out if required.  That is, if the team is still up (as [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407007/12708583) says it got deleted).

Comment: @10Rep How could you "test it out"? You already have more than 200 points in SO, so you are already eligible for the assoc bonus as it is.

Comment: I'm confused by this being tagged with [tag:status-deferred].  Wasn't this issue fixed?

Comment: @Anonymous It was fixed at one point but regressed. This is reporting the later regression.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry. We were spamming in a private team without the intention of gaining an association bonus. The rule for that particular team was that we could spam without end and gain rep from that. Today, we had some trouble and my main account (Tech Expert Wizard) deleted everyone in the team and then cancelled the free subscription. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, but if this is a recurring bug it still needs fixing ;-) Deleting the team won't help in fixing/taking away the association bonus, that is still attached to your [account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331060/369802) even when you delete the profiles you earned it on.

Comment: @Tin lol, yea... do I still get to keep my association bonus?

Comment: Well all the previous people apparently did get to keep it, like [that first post I linked said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369598/6380541), so ... I guess so :)