# Allow new community users to answer/comment questions using their reputation from other communities (if they have)

Tags: feature-request

Recently I was searching for a youtube live streaming query and landed on the stackexchange's webapps community, saw the question and answers but didn't find a solution. I kept on trying various options at youtube and eventually found a solution sometime later. I immediately wanted to go back to the webapps's question and wanted to record an answer for my own reference and someone else but couldn't do so because I don't have an account there (seems fair).

So I used an existing account and create a new one here, went to the question page and bam! I cannot answer or comment due to being a new user in the community. But hey SO, I got the answer and I have sufficient reputation points in other communities so I am not 'that' new.

So here's my more-of-a-request type of question. Can we allow users to use reputation from other communities as a validity to post answer or comments to new communities when they join them?

Perhaps other actions can be blocked but at least users with enough rep on other sites can at least post an answer if they have sufficient rep in any of the community.

Comment: *I cannot answer* You should be able to answer unless you're banned for low-quality contributions already, or suspended. The comment rep restriction won't be an issue once you reach 200 rep anywhere, since then you'll get the association bonus (+100) when joining other sites.

Comment: [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103558/how-do-i-stop-a-youtube-live-stream) was the question I was trying to answer. I had to post another question on the site that received an upvote (+10) and got able to answer it then. I was not marked for low-quality but I can remember that I saw a **highly active** badge on the question. Does that fall under protected question?

Comment: The answer below mentioned it. Thanks

Comment: Please note that after user is been on SE network for some time they usually know that asking about particular site policy should be done on the corresponding meta for that site or on global one. Generally "why I can't post on {some site on SE network}" can't be answered on meta.SO. In this case answer that is specific to SO also likely applies to WebApps.SE, but it is rather exception than the rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Users are always allowed to answer questions, regardless of reputation.

The only exception is ["protected"/"highly active" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), which require at least 10 reputation earned on that site in order to answer. Protected questions are, however, quite rare, and questions are only protected when we specifically *want* to avoid answers from brand-new users (e.g., because the question is a common spam target, and/or because the question already has received a lot of repetitive answers).

Comments are different. First off, though, **comments are *not answers***. Commenting is [a privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) requiring at least 50 reputation. This means that new users to a Stack Exchange site are not allowed to comment.

However, the feature you are requesting already exists in the form of [association bonuses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254472/100-reputation-bonus-upon-joining-new-stack-exchange-site?). If you are trusted on one Stack Exchange site, then when you create a new account on another Stack Exchange site, you get a +100 reputation bonus to your new account. This gets you over the "new user" hump, including granting you the privilege of commenting anywhere. However, the association bonus is not counted for the 10 reputation needed to answer "protected"/"highly active" questions. For those, you have to actually earn at least 10 reputation on the site where you are wanting to answer.

The only difference between this existing feature and your proposal is the definition of "sufficient rep". For the association bonus, "sufficient rep" is defined as having at least 200 reputation on one of the Stack Exchange sites. At this reputation level, we can be pretty confident that you have been around long enough and participated enough to understand the site policies. Before this level, it's much less likely. Stack Exchange sites are very different from other forums on the web, and that creates a lot of misunderstandings from new users.

Comment: It was a highly active question then. But now it is no more. May be that's why. Thanks for clearing that up and association bonus.