# people pointing to other SE sites as more appropriate

Tags: discussion, comments, stack-exchange

I try to craft good question on StackOverflow, giving examples and partially working code bot more often then not, people are religiously pointing 
me to other SE sites:

"...here is my solution, but it is ugly and to long is there a shorter/optimized way to do it "
 - GO TO CodeGolf! + down_vote!

"this is my workaround for the problem, is there a more elegant way to do this?"
 - GO TO CodeRevew! + down_vote!

Even if the scope of the other SE sites is some times more specific, StackOverflow is more powerful, with bigger user base and if the topic is related to real world programming problem I don't see the point to use the "smaller" sites (if I m not active beta user there...).

Comment: Working code with a general 'can this be improved' question is *off topic* here; that's too broad for Stack Overflow. But it is on-topic for CodeReview, so pointing the OP to a place where they can get an answer is *helpful*.

Comment: That's not even what CodeGolf.SE is for...

Comment: OK I got the point .. adding a partially working ugly code is not a good practice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it a good way for Stack Overflow to split and distribute topics over different websites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253824/is-it-a-good-way-for-stack-overflow-to-split-and-distribute-topics-over-differen)

Comment: @gnat This question is radically different from that one.  Related, sure, duplicate, certainly not.

Answer (score 7):

You're quite right that this is problematic behavior from these users.  They shouldn't be (just) pointing you to another site just because that site exists; they should be explaining to you why the question is *not* on topic on SO (because it sounds like it's not).  The fact that the question *is* on topic on another site doesn't mean that it's *not* on topic on SO, even though there's a very strong chance that it is the case.

If they want to point you to a site where the question *would* be appropriate in addition to explaining why it's *not* appropriate on SO, then that's fine.

As for your scenarios, questions of the form, "[code dump] please improve" are really too broad for SO.  SO is for *specific* questions, with a well defined and reasonably narrow problem statement.  It's not necessarily the case that *all* questions similar to that will be off topic, but there's a reasonably high likelihood.